# Field Integrity Exception occures when importing library in js controller

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, controller, static-resources, import

I'm trying to import pdf.js to my controller. I've created a static resource called "pdf" and attached pdf.js file to it. Then I'm trying to import that with ES6 import keyword but when I try to save the file I'm getting an error: `FIELD_INTEGRITY EXCEPTION  Failed to save InvoiceUploaderController.js: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.InvoiceUploader: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':' [2, 10]: 'pdf': Source`

Here is my controller

```
({
  import pdf from '@salesforce/resourceUri/pdf';
  
  handleUploadFinished: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
    
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
      title: "Success!",
      message: "File " + uploadedFiles[0].name + " Uploaded successfully."
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
  }
});
```

I'm new to Salesforce so I'm confused a little... Somebody please help me to fix that, than you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you created an Aura Component instead of a Lightning Web Component. Aura only [supports ES5 and ES6 Promises](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_supported_es.htm), while LWC supports [almost all major JS features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/get_started_supported_javascript) up to the present. Creating an LWC requires SFDX, as there is no UI in Salesforce for this kind of development yet (no idea when, or if, we'll ever get that kind of feature). You'll want to get [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) if you don't already have it, plus [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode). I also really like [codefriar](https://twitter.com/codefriar)'s excellent [codefriar's pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codefriar.codefriar-s-pack).

Also, static resources are loaded differently; you'll want to look at [lightning-platform-resource-loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation) and the documentation found in [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library). Or, if you want to, you can load your scripts in Aura by reading about [Using External JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm). Just be aware that Aura and LWC are two separate technologies, so you'll need to make sure you're reading the correct documentation.